# MySQL apparently running but not listening on TCP, jdbc can't connect

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, jdbc

I am running MySQL on Ubuntu. `mysql` cli, as does `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`, but I cannot connect using `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection`:

```
java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable (connect failed)
```

`ps` tells me the service is running

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

The file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` includes `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` which contains another `my.cnf` which contains

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
```

Using the cli, `show variables like 'skip_networking'` is `OFF`.

`netstat -l | grep sql` indicates a UNIX domain socket is listening, but nothing on TCP for sql.

Is this why jdbc can't connect?

How do I fix it?

Comment: What are the involved IP addresses and networks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check using `netstat` whether port 3306 is listening or not.

Verify also that the `bind-address` is set to the Ethernet interface address (or "*") and not to the localhost address (this is the new default that replaces skip-networking, and very likely the source of your problems).

**If the line is not present at all it should go with *that* default and work, so commenting the line is also good**.

On some systems, `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` have *different* meanings; namely the former indicates a UNIX connection, the latter a TCP connection. I had this happen to me once, but no longer remember what system it was.

Ensure that the Java socket connection *does* connect to your server address. In a pinch, try using the command line MySQL to connect to the server **using the `--host` parameter** to force a TCP connection.

Finally, just to be sure, `iptables -L -n` should tell you whether the connection might be firewalled.

Comment: `netstat -l | grep 3306` shows nothing, `bind-address=127.0.0.1` in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf`, iptables is all `ACCEPT`. I don't know how to "ensure that the Java socket connection does connect to your server address"

Comment: Try commenting the bind-address directive and restarting MySQL. For Java, you should have a connect string in the JDBC instantiation; what does it say?

Comment: You mean this? `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_test_db?useSSL=false`

Comment: Yes. Try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1; but comment also the bind address line and restart the mysql server.

Comment: Commenting out `bind-address` worked.

Comment: @spraff "edit from OP" would mean that you are another account of LSerni (what is officially allowed, but interacting multiple accounts to each other is not). I think you wanted to say some other. Your edit suggestion will be likely rejected, I suggest to suggest it again, so: simply edit it into the post ("XY worked"), and put into the edit message this: "see comments - OP said XY worked".

Comment: @spraff as peterh said, "edit from OP" is not correct - it might refer to the Original Poster of the *answer*, and that's me :-).

I set the working solution in bold, to indicate that's the one that worked for you.